# Manipulating objects in design view

Tags: vba, excel

I have worked on several projects now where I have been stumped by MS Excel and MS Access where I cannot use VBA to manipulate objects whilst in design view. They are very simple tasks such as changing the name of the labels on a userform in MS Excel or adding new textboxes to a report in MS Access but they seem to be impossible as any macro will only be used upon activation of said userform or report and so everything is just done in runtime.

To focus on one, In MS Excel I want to be able to run a code which will go through all the labels on my userform and rename them from "Label1", "Label2", etc... to "Lbl1", "Lbl2", etc... for instance but I cannot just click a button to run a macro on the design of the userform which would run through all the labels and change their names. If I am able to do this then I can be much more efficent with the rest of my runtime code. Without it, I have the option of renaming every single label I have but there are near 100 labels and I want to do this through VBA as I already can see that it would be very useful to know how to run code in design view of these Visual Basic elements.

Please could you advise whether it is possible to manipulate these VB objects in design view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run code from a normal module to alter the design of a userform. You must have trusted access to the VBA Project in your Trust Center settings. Then it's simply a question of using the `Designer` property of the relevant `VBComponent`:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ctl                   As MSForms.Control
    Dim lCounter              As Long

    lCounter = 1

    For Each ctl In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Userform1").Designer.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
            ctl.Name = "lbl" & lCounter
            lCounter = lCounter + 1
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

The form must not be loaded when you run this.

Answer (score 1):

You can program the project from code if you set a special macro permission.

Details are on Chip's site:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. If you have a designer open for `Form1` and type `Form1.Show` in the immediate pane, the VBE will close the designer before it brings up the form. That's just the way it is.

Now, if you have labels `Label1`, `Label2` and `Label3`, you have what I like to call meaningless identifiers. Renaming them to `Lbl1`, `Lbl2` and `Lbl3` will make things even worse.

And if you're referencing them anywhere in code, renaming them will break your code. It's even worse with buttons or anything else with events you're handling: renaming `Button1` to `Btn1` will not rename the `Button1_Click()` procedure to `Btn1_Click()`.

Use meaningful names. If `Label1` is sitting atop a textbox for, I don't know, some *username*, then name it `lblUserName` or `UserNameLabel`. Use meaningful names. Always.

I've written a refactoring tool for renaming things, that deals with event handlers and many other things; you could right-click a reference to `Label1` in your code, select `Refactor > Rename` from the context menu, enter a new name, and the tool renames all references, and the control itself. The tool in question is called [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com), and does quite a lot more than just letting you rename things, too.

If the labels aren't referenced anywhere in code, then they don't need a name. Why bother?

Comment: Hello Mat, I understand that giving all controls meaningful names is best practice but in this instance I would actually be using the numbers following the word "label" in my code. For instance: Controls("Label" & i & j).caption = ... as it would make the whole process more efficient for what I am doing. I am disappointed by the fact you can't write code to be used in the design stage, I think it would make a huge difference to the speed in which I can work on things.

Comment: @Sammir alternatively you can drop the design stage and generate the UI at runtime.